# How to make object referencing to the same thing?

Tags: java

```
public class Number {
    private int j;
    public Number(){
        j = 3;
    }

    public Number(int m){
        j = m;
    }

    public void SetNum(int n){
        j = n;
    }

    public int GetNum(){
        return j;
        }

    }
```

/// (different file, same directory)

```
    public class User {
        private Number jim;

        public User(){
                this.jim = new Number();
            }

            public static void main(String []args){
                User keith = new User();
                User justin = new User();
                ??????????????????????????
            }
     }
```

I want `keith.jim = justin.jim` and `justin.jim = keith.jim`. Such that if i do `keith.jim.SetNum(34)`, both `keith` and `justin's` `jim.j` will be `34`. How to do that? This idea will be implement in a bigger piece of code.

Also, `user.java` and `Number`.java must exist. The context cannot be changed,I can add new methods but I cannot alter the context in `Number` (E.G put j in user instead of Number). Each user must have a number object which every users is referencing to as well.

Comment: Just do `keith = justin;`. That will be enough. And can you also change the name of your class `Number`? There is already a class with that name in Java API.

Comment: User justin = keith ; both will refer same object

Comment: Create a new constructor for `User` taking a `Number` is also a possibility

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested creating just one `User` object. An alternative would be to have two `User` objects, but with the same reference for the value of the `jim` field:

```
User keith = new User();
User justin = new User();
justin.jim = keith.jim;
```

This would be useful if you have other fields where `keith` and `justin` need to be different, but any change in the object that the value of the `jim` field refers to must be seen by both.

Both of these are valid options, depending on your requirements.

A few points, however:

- This means the original value of `justin.jim` because pointless; you could consider adding a `User` constructor taking a `Number` reference for the initial value of the field, allowing you to write:

  ```
  User justin = new User(keith.jim);
  ```
- Shared mutable state like this can become tricky to reason about, particularly in the face of multiple threads
- As noted in comments, you should rename your `Number` class to be something that *isn't* in `java.lang` (or `java.util` etc, if possible).
- You should follow Java naming conventions for your methods, using camelCase instead of PascalCase - I'd call them `getValue` and `setValue`, personally.

Comment: _if i do keith.jim.SetNum(34), both keith and justin's jim.j will be 34_. I don't think so this will be achieved.

Comment: @eatSleepCode: Yes it will - if both `justin.jim` and `keith.jim` are references to the same instance of `Number`. There'll only be one (used) `Number` instance in that case. Why do you think that wouldn't work?

Comment: oh! yes was thinking of something else, `jim` is Number instance.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   User keith = new User();
   User justin = keith;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   User keith = new User();
   User justin = keith;
```

Now both will refer to the same object, any change make in the **keith** will reflected to the **justin** because both are referring to same object.